# Remove the space from the beginning of file name inside the zip file, without extracting the zip file

Tags: shell, zip

I have n numbers of zip files in a directory. inside these zip files, there is space in the beginning of file name. I just want to remove this space without extracting the zip file.

I tried a shell script, as below.

```
#!/bin/sh
for zip in *.zip
do
    unzipped=unzip $zip
    trimmed=echo "${unzipped}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
    #Want to zip the file here with the same name
done
```

Need help in this script or if any short method will be most welcome.

Comment: Since the zip command doesn't provide an option for renaming the files, I think you can't do this, at least not within the usual realm of shell programming. There are libraries available for other programming languages, which you could use. For instance, if you write your script in Ruby, you could install the *rubyzip* gem (=library), which supposedly can do this: See [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/185443) and [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubyzip/). There are probably similar libraries available for i.e. Perl and Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the tool `zipnote` which is part of Info-ZIP's zip package. Based on your code example above, a minimal working example could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for zip in *.zip
do
    ZIPNOTES=$(zipnote "$zip")
    TRIMMED=$(echo "$ZIPNOTES" | sed -e 's/^@[ \t]\{2,\}\(.*\)/&\n@=\1/')
    echo "$TRIMMED" | zipnote -w "$zip"
done
```

or as one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
for zip in *.zip; do zipnote "$zip" | sed -e 's/^@[ \t]\{2,\}\(.*\)/&\n@=\1/' | zipnote -w "$zip"; done
```

### Long answer

Let's assume you have a zip archive `archive.zip` containing the files `\ \ foo` and `bar`, the utility `zipnote` outputs the following lines:

```
$ zipnote archive.zip
@   foo
@ (comment above this line)
@ bar
@ (comment above this line)
@ (zip file comment below this line)
```

According to `man zipnote`:

> The  names of the files in the zipfile can also be changed in this way.
>          This is done by following lines like
>               "@ name"
>          in the created temporary file (called foo.tmp here) with lines like
>               "@=newname"
>          and then using the -w option as above.

Hence, to rename the file `\ \ foo` within the zip archive, you have to append the line

```
@=foo
```

just beneath the corresponding line

```
@   foo
```

and pipe it into `zipnote -w archive.zip`. The latter is done with a slight modification of your `sed` command which matches on lines containing an `@` symbol followed by two or more whitespaces, grouping the rest of the line and appending the trimmed line beneath.

Comment: thank you so much, it helped, though i need to modify it, but it helped in creating the blueprint of solution.

Comment: You're welcome! You can contribute to the community by posting your optimizations as an alternative answer so that other facing the same problem benefit from your efforts.